# Is something wrong with my hash function

Tags: c++, hashtable, collision-detection

I am trying to implement a spatial hash, and am using the hash function from [Optimized Spatial Hashing for Collision Detection of Deformable Objects](http://matthias-mueller-fischer.ch/publications/tetraederCollision.pdf), `hash(x, y, z) = (x p1 xor y p2 xor z p3) mod n` where n is the number of buckets in the hash table.

My code for the hash function is:

```
int SpatialHash::hash(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return (((x * P1) ^ (y * P2) ^ (z * P3)) % TABLE_SIZE);
}
```

with defines:

```
#define P1 73856093
#define P2 19349663
#define P3 83492791
#define TABLE_SIZE 2000
```

I just tried iterating through a list of elements, and when I tried to place the vertex 1, -1, 0 into the table it gave me an index of -196. Did I mess up somewhere with my hash function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo of a negative number is negative. For example:

```
-7 % 3 = -1
```

What want something like this instead:

```
int positiveModulo(int number, int modulo)
{
    int result = number % mudulo;
    if (result < 0)
        result += modulo;
    return result;
}
```

Or to avoid branches:

```
int positiveModulo(int number, int modulo)
{
    int result = number % mudulo;
    result += modulo;
    result %= modulo;
    return result;
}
```

This will give you:

```
positiveModulo(-7, 3) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a funny question, because the sign of the result of the modulo operation is something programming language designers and mathematicians like to argue about.

In fact, in ISO C++, the sign of the modulo operation with negative operand is implementation-defined.
Clever languages have a `mod` as well as a `rem` to catch both cases.
Have a look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) and their table of programming languages.

It's funny how it is split nearly 50:50.

Now the solution to your problem: Just add a positive modulo operation.
The easiest solution would be to use `abs(...) % N`, as `(-a) mod N + a mod N = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define P1 73856093
#define P2 19349663
#define P3 83492791
#define TABLE_SIZE 2000
int positive_mod(int i, int n)
{
    /* constexpr */ int shift = 64*sizeof i - 1;
    int m = i%n;
    return m+ (m>>shift & n);
}
int hasha(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return positive_mod(((x * P1) ^ (y * P2) ^ (z * P3)) ,TABLE_SIZE);
}





int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = hasha(1,-1,0);
    cout << ret << endl;
}
```

Comment: ahhh it's an overflow error? I'm confused though, becuase shouldn't the modulo operation not return negative? Can I just use a long int instead?

Comment: I downvoted you because you used macros and `using namespace std;`. The whole point of answering is to make your code better than the questioners.

Comment: And I upvoted you because f*ck this guy ^. You banged out some quick code to show what you were talking about. Thanks.